# Using Gesture detection to show/hide custom bottom menu?

Tags: android, android-gesture

In my application I need to show and hide a view(custom menu) only in screen's bottom if a user swipe from bottom to up and similarly it should hide the view if user swipes the view down.The swiping thing is similar to [navigation drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) introduced in android recently but I am not getting how do I detect the bottom-up swipe in my application to show the view.I could have used SlidingDrawer but that has been deprecated since API 17.Please help me .

[image] ---> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](http://androidexample.com/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=95&aaid=118) . I don't think use SlidingDrawer

Comment: It is close to my question's answer but I want to make sure that user swipe started from bottom of the screen to upward not from somewhere in the middle to upward